# Find tension through rope binding hammock to two trees

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, geometry

An object with mass lies in a hammock tied to a tree on each end with a rope. The two ropes form the same angle of 45° with the horizontal. How should someone proceed if s/he wants to find the force through one of the rope ?

---

We know that $\sin 45° = \cos 45°$

We split our forces in horizontal and vertical components by using trigonometry. The horizontal tensions must cancel each others, and the two vertical tensions must cancel the gravity force that pulls the person down.

We can set up two system of equations to solve for the tension in the ropes. The result would directly depend on the angle of the rope with the horizontal. An angle below 45° would increase the tension in the rope, and an angle above 60° would decrease it

---

Is my understanding correct ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Feel free to comment if anything is unclear

Comment: @VinalV Feel free to post an answer. If it seems corrrect, you can just say it and I will accept your answer

Comment: Your calculated tensions are correct. And your statement about which force is larger when the angle changes is also correct.

Comment: What is **your** question? Remember [check my work], and [homework problems] aren't considered good questions for this site.

Comment: @JAlex Did I conceptually correctly understand that I need to proceed like I did ? Split up the force components in horizontal and vertical parts through trigonometry ? Instead of a hammock, we could as well have any other object too ? We just need the mass of the object, and the angle of the ropes to the horizontal, is this the case ? I have trouble believing it can be that simple so maybe I'm missing something

Comment: As @VinalV said, yes everything checks out. You can do the check yourself, but adding up all the forces and see that you have achieved balance. If you made a mistake, there would be a force imbalance. The only suggestion I have is to add a free body diagram. A simple triangle would suffice here.

Comment: @JAlex Uh yes, in fact, a free body diagram could be very helpful. Didn't thought about that, thanks ! It definitely would make the overview simpler and less prone to mistakes I guess. Feel free to post your comment as an answer, I will accept and upvote it if you want. Otherwise I will answer my own question so it doesn't appear in the unanswered questions anymore